# pandas nested loops out of range of list

Tags: pandas, loops, yahoo-finance, stocks

I am starting with a list called returnlist:

```
len(returnlist)
9
returnlist[0]

    AAPL    AMZN    BAC GE  GM  GOOG    GS  SNP XOM
Date                                    
2012-01-09  60.247143   178.559998  6.27    18.860001   22.840000   309.218842  94.690002   89.053848   85.500000
2012-01-10  60.462856   179.339996  6.63    18.719999   23.240000   309.556641  98.330002   89.430771   85.720001
2012-01-11  60.364285   178.899994  6.87    18.879999   24.469999   310.957520  99.760002   88.984619   85.080002
2012-01-12  60.198570   175.929993  6.79    18.930000   24.670000   312.785645  101.209999  87.838463   84.739998
2012-01-13  59.972858   178.419998  6.61    18.840000   24.290001   310.475647  98.959999   87.792313   84.879997
```

I want to get the daily  leg returns and then use cumsum to get the accumulated returns.

```
weeklyreturns=[]
for i in range (1,10):
    returns=pd.DataFrame()
    for stock in returnlist[i]:
        if stock not in returnlist[i]:
            returns[stock]=np.log(returnlist[i][stock]).diff()
    weeklyreturns.append(returns)
```

the error that I am getting is :

```
----> 4     for stock in returnlist[i]:
      5         if stock not in returnlist[i]:
      6             returns[stock]=np.log(returnlist[i][stock]).diff()

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `len(returnlist) == 9`, that means the last item of `returnlist` is `returnlist[8]`.

When you iterate over `range(1,10)`, you will start at `returnlist[1]` and eventually get to `returnlist[9]`, which doesn't exist.

It seems that what you actually need is to iterate over `range(0,9)`.